# Restructuing and formatting data frame columns

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, multidplyr

```
dfin <- 

ID   SEQ   GRP   C1   C2   C3   T1   T2   T3
1     1     1    0     5    8   0     1   2
1     2     1    5     10   15  5     6   7
2     1     2    20    25   30  0     1   2
```

`C1` is the concentration (`CONC`) at T1 (`TIME`) and so on. This is what I want as an output:

```
dfout <- 

ID   SEQ   GRP  CONC  TIME
1     1     1    0     0
1     1     1    5     1
1     1     1    8     2
1     2     1    5     5
1     2     1    10    6
1     2     1    15    7
2     1     2    20    0
2     1     2    25    1
2     1     2    30    2
```

The `dfin` has much more columns for `Cx` and `Tx` where x is the number of concentration readings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `data.table::melt`, with its capability of melting the table into multiple columns based on the columns pattern:

```
library(data.table)
melt(
    setDT(df), 
    id.vars=c("ID", "SEQ", "GRP"), 
    # columns starts with C and T should be melted into two separate columns
    measure.vars=patterns("^C", "^T"),     
    value.name=c('CONC', 'TIME')
)[order(ID, SEQ)][, variable := NULL][]

#   ID SEQ GRP CONC TIME
#1:  1   1   1    0    0
#2:  1   1   1    5    1
#3:  1   1   1    8    2
#4:  1   2   1    5    5
#5:  1   2   1   10    6
#6:  1   2   1   15    7
#7:  2   1   2   20    0
#8:  2   1   2   25    1
#9:  2   1   2   30    2
```

---

Or if the value column names follow the pattern `[CT][0-9]`, you can use `reshape` from base R by specifying the `sep=""` which will split the value columns name by the letter/digit separation due to this default setting (from ?reshape):

> ```
> split = if (sep == "") {
>             list(regexp = "[A-Za-z][0-9]", include = TRUE)
>         } else {
>             list(regexp = sep, include = FALSE, fixed = TRUE)}
> ```

```
reshape(df, varying=-(1:3), idvar=c("ID", "SEQ", "GRP"), 
        dir="long", sep="", v.names=c("CONC", "TIME"))

#   ID SEQ GRP time CONC TIME
#1:  1   1   1    1    0    5
#2:  1   2   1    1    5   10
#3:  2   1   2    1   20   25
#4:  1   1   1    2    8    0
#5:  1   2   1    2   15    5
#6:  2   1   2    2   30    0
#7:  1   1   1    3    1    2
#8:  1   2   1    3    6    7
#9:  2   1   2    3    1    2
```

Comment: Thank you. I applied data.table method to my whole dataframe but got this warning `Warning message: In melt.data.table(setDT(data1), id.vars = c("SUB", "SEQ", "PER",  :
  'measure.vars' [TRT, T1, T2, T3, ...] are not all of the same type. By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'double'. All measure variables not of type 'double' will be coerced to. Check DETAILS in ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.`   is this a critical warning here?

Comment: You need to check the data types of all the columns of your data frame by `sapply(df, class)`. And make sure they are what you expected. The warning means some of the columns are not of numeric type, and if coerced to numeric type, you may get unexpected NAs.

Comment: Thanks for that. I found where the problem is. I had another column in the data frame called `TRT` (starts with T) and is an interger. The `TRT` column is one of the `id.vars` in the data frame. Is there a way to avoid other than renaming this column?

Comment: If you don't care about losing track of which C or which T the value comes from, i.e, the `x` value after C or T, then you can change the pattern to `^C\\d` and `^T\\d`, assuming `Cx` or `Tx`, x is always a number.

Comment: I do care about where the value is coming from because C1 should be associated with T1 and so on. So may be renaming that column better? in my case, yes, x is always a number.

Comment: That's what I would do. Rename it before reshaping and change it back later.

Comment: I ran the code with what you have suggested `^C\\d` and `^T\\d` and gave similar output the one posted in the answer. So, it should be fine then.